# How to backup script for subset of tables in SQL Express DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have developed a SQL Express database. I need to backup all but one table in that database in an automated way. I was thinking i could write a SQL script to do this, trigger it using sqlcmd from a batch file but not sure how to write that SQL script.

I was also thinking, if nothing else possible, i could create a second db that has the tables i want to backup then i write a script that copys data 'into' the second db and then do a auto backup of that entire db. This has the disadvantage of having a procrastinated unpacking of that backup when wanting to use it - its not a small install script.

Is this a possibility, is it the only option or is there tools for SQL Express to do this?

Comment: Does the complexity required to exclude one table measure up to the requirement to exclude it? Is it because it has sensitive data or is it because it has too much data?

Comment: its a huge table and would put too much load on the server for the frequency i want to run the backup. Everything is is small data.

Comment: You could also put the tables on two different filegroups and just backup one filegroup. Not 100% on whether you can just selectively restore one filegroup but it's definitely something to research

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to exclude just one table while backing up .Few things i could think of

1.Right click database ->Tasks ->generate scripts ->exclude  the table you want and choose to save the script and run this every time

2.you could also choose Export option,but since you are using SQL Express,you wont have the option to save this package

Comment: what about the plan to export to a 'backup database' using the 'select * from db1.xxx into db2.yyy' for the tables i want and then backing db2 up in its entirety

Answer (score 0):

Keep the large table in a different database and just backup the original database. You can still use the large table even in a different database, i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyDb.dbo.SomeTable s
JOIN OtherDb.dbo.LargeTable l
ON (expression);
```